# Is there way to use 'in operator if padas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, filtering

Hi I want to filter a large dataframe based on if a columns row is in a list object.

I tried the code below but i get an error:

```
df[df['castaway_id'] in [1,2,3,4]]
```

[image]

Is there an alternative to this or another way to do the same

Comment: `df[df['castaway_id'].isin([1,2,3,4])]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the usual way is to use the `isin` method as below :

```py
df[df['castaway_id'].isin([1,2,3,4])]
```

Comment: Thanks ! that helped . do you know if it is even possible to use the in operator in this case

Comment: Glad I cloud help. You can mark the answer as the correct one. To answer your other question, no because it will compare the entire column with an element of the list.